# How I can fill a collection from a database and connect this collection to ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

How I can fill a collection from a database and connect this collection to a ComboBox?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty low, Gold. A lot of your unanswered questions have good, accurate answers.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to fill a DataTable with your data, and then set it as your ComboBox's DataSource.  Here's how to fill a DataTable from SQL Server and use it with a ComboBox named "comboBox1":

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = 
        new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, FullName FROM tblPeople", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to replace "your connection string" with a valid connection string, of course.  To see how to build connection strings, check out [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com).

Now go accept some answers (including this one).  :)